# WEKA - neural network - MLP - data model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, weka, prediction

My aim is to predict weather parameters (air_temp, humidity) using data from Station X,Y on Station Z. Where X is the official data, Y and Z stations are observations. All of these stations (observation points) geographically closely located. 
Here is sample data file in CSV format, 
X will be test data, Y and Z are training data.

```
date_time,StationName,air_temp,dewpoint,humidity,windspeed,windchill,pressure
2014-07-01,X,11,8.74811,86,0,11,1017.22
2014-07-02,X,16.2222,12.7651,80,1,16.2222,1019.02
2014-07-03,X,21.3889,13.039,59,0,21.3889,1020.37
2014-07-04,X,21.4444,12.8294,58,3,21.4444,1020.74
2014-07-05,X,21.4444,12.8294,58,3,21.33,1020.71
2014-07-06,X,21.4444,12.8294,58,9,21.4444,1020.74
2014-07-07,X,21.3889,12.5119,57,9,21.3889,1020.74
2014-07-08,X,21.3889,12.2423,56,9,21.3889,1020.74
2014-07-09,X,21.3889,12.2423,56,11,21.3889,1020.74
2014-07-01,Y,13.7,9.4,75,1,13.9,1020.3
2014-07-02,Y,13.7,9.4,75,2,13.9,1020.3
2014-07-03,Y,13.7,9.4,76,2,13.9,1020.3
2014-07-04,Y,13.6,9.4,76,3,13.9,1020.4
2014-07-05,Y,13.6,9.4,76,3,13.9,1020.3
2014-07-06,Y,13.6,9.4,76,2,13.3,1020.3
2014-07-07,Y,13.6,9.4,76,2,13.3,1020.4
2014-07-08,Y,13.5,9.4,76,1,13.3,1020.4
2014-07-09,Y,13.5,9.4,76,2,13.3,1020.4
2014-07-01,Z,13.2,10,82,0,13.3,1016.3
2014-07-02,Z,13.2,10,82,0,13.3,1016.3
2014-07-03,Z,13.1,10,82,0,13.3,1016.3
2014-07-04,Z,13.1,10,82,0,13.3,1016.3
2014-07-05,Z,13.1,10,82,0,13.3,1016.3
2014-07-06,Z,13.1,10,82,0,13.3,1016.3
2014-07-07,Z,13.1,10,82,0,13.3,1016.3
2014-07-08,Z,13,10,82,0,12.8,1016.3
2014-07-09,Z,12.9,10,82,0,12.8,1016.2
```

How do approach this problem using WEKA tool, particularly using Artificial Neural networks (MLP) or other ? If I want predict temperature on station Z how do instruct weka to do this?